# Is glass a liquid?

Tags: condensed-matter, amorphous-solids, glass

I was told by a condensed matter physicist that glass is a liquid with a very high viscosity (it would be more precise to say that it is a [supercooled liquid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling)). The example given was that in cathedral windows the glass flows very, very slowly, so they are thicker at the bottom.

I recently read this [article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=fact-fiction-glass-liquid) in Scientific American, which contradicts the previous statement.

Are there any serious studies about this aspect of glass? Is it only a problem of definition?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55829/2451) Phys.SE post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

False.

To quote from the specific section in the [list of common misconceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions#cite_ref-335):

> Glass does not flow at room temperature as a high-viscosity
>   liquid. Although glass shares some molecular properties found in
>   liquids, glass at room temperature is an "amorphous solid" that only
>   begins to flow above the glass transition temperature, though the
>   exact nature of the glass transition is not considered settled among
>   theorists and scientists. Panes of stained glass windows are
>   often thicker at the bottom than at the top, and this has been cited
>   as an example of the slow flow of glass over centuries. However, this
>   unevenness is due to the window manufacturing processes used at the
>   time. Normally the thick end of glass would be installed at the bottom
>   of the frame, but it is also common to find old windows where the
>   thicker end has been installed to the sides or the top. No
>   such distortion is observed in other glass objects, such as sculptures
>   or optical instruments, that are of similar or even greater age. One
>   researcher estimated in 1998 that for glass to actually "flow" at room
>   temperatures would take many times the age of the
>   earth.

Comment: I love the list of common misconceptions!